# in R, what is the difference between get("abc") and eval(parse(text="abc"))

Tags: r, parsing, eval

I'd like to know the difference(s) between those two operations; in this example, they seem to work the same, but there must be situations where one will work and the other not. I just can't figure out when this would be the case.

```
> a <- 298
> eval(parse(text = "a"))
[1] 298
> get("a")
[1] 298
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your example the two functions works the same. But the difference shows up when you want to evaluate an expression of a particular form, example :

```
eval(parse(text = "x <- 1"))
```

The **eval(parse(...))** command will evaluate the expression in input while **get** will just return the value stocked in it, in this particular example it will not work with **get**, because it is an expression (not a variable). So **eval(parse(...))** is primarily used to evaluate expressions that you construct (by using **paste**, etc) in your program.

Comment: And of course if you search around for "R   fortune()  eval(parse" you'll get a famous quote   :-)